# How to indent a chart in quarto

Tags: quarto

I'd like to indent a chart so that it matches my bullet point list, how can I indent a chart in Quarto?

I'm plotting using R code blocks, not just inserting an image.

Thx!

Comment: Could you provide a MWE?